# ASP.net MVC 5 Areas in existing project not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've been trying to set up a new Area in my current project following details instructions but I'm not able to get a successful result.

Could somebody help me, please? Here is my code so far:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MesaServicio
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Main_default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "MesaServicio.Controllers" }
            );


            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "signin-google",
               url: "signin-google",
               defaults: new
                   {
                       controller = "Account",
                       action = "ExternalLoginCallback"
                   },
                namespaces: new string[] { "MesaServicio.Controllers" }
               );
        }
    }
}
```

**AdminAreaRegistration.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MesaServicio.Areas.Admin
{
    public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller="Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "MesaServicio.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**AdminController.cs**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MesaServicio.Models;

namespace MesaServicio.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Admin/Admin
        public ActionResult Prueba()
        {
            return View(db.Corps.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

**Area files structure screenshot**

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fd4O.jpg)

**Global.asax.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MesaServicio
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

**Link trigger**

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Admin", new {area = "admin" })"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Admin</a></li>
```

**RESULT**

> https://localhost:44306/admin/
>
> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Comment: Are there any trace information available? like log4net etc.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AdminController`doesn't have an `Index` action, it instead has a `Prueba` action. Try renaming method `Prueba` to `Index`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12701579)

Comment: Thanks, @tarzanbappa. I edited to provide an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

The method Index() does not exist in AdminController

The only method you have is Prueba(), which does not receive parameter "area".

You should add something like this

```
    public ActionResult Index(string area)
            { 
                //Do whatever you want
                return View();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your default route for the Area to use the "Index" action:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller="Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "MesaServicio.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Which you have not defined in your Admin Area controller:

```
namespace MesaServicio.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Admin/Admin
        public ActionResult Prueba()
        {
            return View(db.Corps.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Either define the "Index" action for that Controller, or change the default to an action that does exist, which in your case the only defined action is "Prueba"

Answer (score 1):

In an ASP.NET MVC area application, you can link within an area as you would in any MVC application. For example, you can call the ActionLink method, or you can call any other routine that takes a controller or action name (such as the RedirectToAction method).

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the possibilities for others:

You are referencing action Index in Admin controller which does not exist, so you have three possibilities.

1. Rename action Prueba to Index
2. Add new Action called Index
3. Add ActionName attribute so you let MVC know what is happening

   ```
   [ActionName("Index")]
   public ActionResult Prueba()
   {
       return View(db.Corps.ToList());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, its worked for me

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "AdminRoute",
                    url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    namespaces: new[] { "Admin.Areas.DESK.Controllers" }
              );
```

- Copy and paste this code above the default route in Routeconfig.cs
- Remove the AreaRegistration.cs from project
- Clean the project,Rebuild and run..